# How do I dynamically add an input field into a cell inside my html table row in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html-table

This is my code:

```
var tab=document.getElementById("quarter_details");
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.type = "text";
input.placeholder = "dd/mm/yyyy";
input.id = "vac";

var row = tab.insertRow(5);
var cell = row.insertCell(0);
var cell1 = row.insertCell(1);

cell.innerHTML = "<b>Date:</b>";
cell1.innerHTML = input; //[object HTMLInputElement]
```

When I run the code, the input text field doesn't appear. What do I do?

**EDIT:** Tried using `cell1.appendChild = input`. Now it shows an empty cell, with no input field

Comment: could you show us your html (if it isn't sensitiv) ? because there is a lot of way to do that and so we could show you many way that work in case and you will be able to select the best for you

Comment: I have to do it dynamically, using `javascript`, as this is the project requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) method:

```
cell1.appendChild(input);
```

Comment: The cell gets created, but the input field is not showing. Just an empty cell.

Comment: You mention in your question edit that you tried `appendChild = input`, that is incorrect. `appendChild` is a method which needs to be called with parenthesis, so `cell1.appendChild(input)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML). Here's a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

```js
const createDateTimeInput = (forCell, id) => {
  forCell.textContent = ``; // empty the cell
  forCell.insertAdjacentHTML(
    `beforeend`, 
    `<b>Date</b> <input type="text" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" id="${id}">`);
};

const firstCellOfSecondRow = 
  document.querySelector(`table tbody tr:nth-child(2) > td`);
setTimeout(() => createDateTimeInput(firstCellOfSecondRow, `vac`), 2000);
```

```css
thead th {
  text-align: left
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>first column</th>
      <th>second column</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```